# Why does my tkinter messagebox not show up in my pygame window?

Tags: python, tkinter

I coded a snake game and whenever you hit your own body, a message box should show up asking u to play again. However, when I do hit the body, my python pygame window just closes without showing the message box. I coded all this in Idle, could it be because I'm using idle? Or is there a problem with my code?

Here are my code:

```
import math
import random
import pygame
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

class cube (object) :
    rows = 20
    w = 500
    def __init__(self,start,dirnx=1,dirny=0,color=(255,0,0)):
        self.pos = start
        self.dirnx = 1
        self.dirny = 0
        self.color = color
    
    def move(self, dirnx, dirny) :
        self.dirnx = dirnx
        self.dirny = dirny
        self.pos = (self.pos[0]+ self.dirnx, self.pos[1] + self.dirny)

    def draw(self, surface, eyes=False) :
        dis = self.w // self.rows
        i = self.pos[0]
        j = self.pos[1]

        pygame.draw.rect(surface, self.color, (i*dis+1,j*dis+1, dis-2, dis-2))
        if eyes:
            centre = dis//2
            radius = 3
            circleMiddle = (i*dis+centre-radius,j*dis+8)
            circleMiddle2 = (i*dis + dis -radius*2, j*dis+8)
            pygame.draw.circle(surface, (0,0,0), circleMiddle, radius)
            pygame.draw.circle(surface, (0,0,0), circleMiddle2, radius)


class snake(object) :
    body = []
    turns = {}
    def __init__(self, color, pos) :
        self.color = color
        self.head = cube(pos)
        self.body.append(self.head)
        self.dirnx = 0
        self.dirny = 1

    def move(self) :
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()

            keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

            for key in keys:
                if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                    self.dirnx = -1
                    self.dirny = 0
                    self.turns[self.head.pos[:]] = [self.dirnx, self.dirny]

                elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                    self.dirnx = 1
                    self.dirny = 0
                    self.turns[self.head.pos[:]] = [self.dirnx, self.dirny]

                elif keys[pygame.K_UP]:
                    self.dirnx = 0
                    self.dirny = -1
                    self.turns[self.head.pos[:]] = [self.dirnx, self.dirny]

                elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                    self.dirnx = 0
                    self.dirny = 1
                    self.turns[self.head.pos[:]] = [self.dirnx, self.dirny]

        for i, c in enumerate(self.body) :
            p = c.pos[:]
            if p in self.turns:
                turn = self.turns[p]
                c.move(turn[0], turn[1])
                if i == len(self.body)-1:
                    self.turns.pop(p)
            else:
                if c.dirnx == -1 and c.pos[0] <= 0: c.pos = (c.rows-1, c.pos[1])
                elif c.dirnx == 1 and c.pos[0] >= c.rows-1: c.pos = (0,c.pos[1])
                elif c.dirny == 1 and c.pos[1] >= c.rows-1: c.pos = (c.pos[0], 0)
                elif c.dirny == -1 and c.pos[1] <= 0: c.pos = (c.pos[0],c.rows-1)
                else: c.move(c.dirnx,c.dirny)

    def reset(self, pos) :
        self.head = cube(pos)
        self.body = []
        self.body.append(self.head)
        self.turns = {}
        self.dirnx = 0
        self.dirny = 1

    def addCube(self) :
        tail = self.body[-1]
        dx, dy = tail.dirnx, tail.dirny

        if dx == 1 and dy == 0: #if an elif statements checking which direction the tail is moving
            self.body.append(cube((tail.pos[0]-1,tail.pos[1])))
#appending a cube to the tail. checking if we r moving in a certain direction and then adding the snack cube to the pos 1 less than tail cube
        elif dx == -1 and dy == 0:
            self.body.append(cube((tail.pos[0]+1,tail.pos[1])))
        elif dx == 0 and dy == 1:
            self.body.append(cube((tail.pos[0],tail.pos[1]-1)))
        elif dx == 0 and dy == -1:
            self.body.append(cube((tail.pos[0],tail.pos[1]+1)))

        self.body[-1].dirnx = dx
        self.body[-1].dirny = dy

    def draw(self, surface) :
        for i, c in enumerate(self.body):
            if i == 0:
                c.draw(surface, True)
            else:
                c.draw(surface)

def drawGrid(w, rows, surface) :
    sizeBtwn = w // rows

    x = 0
    y = 0
    for l in range(rows) :
        x = x + sizeBtwn
        y = y + sizeBtwn

        pygame.draw.line(surface,(255,255,255), (x,0), (x,w))
        pygame.draw.line(surface,(255,255,255), (0,y), (w,y))
        

def redrawWindow(surface) :
    global rows, width, s, snack
    surface.fill((0,0,0))
    s.draw(surface)
    snack.draw(surface)
    drawGrid(width,rows, surface)
    pygame.display.update()

def randomSnack(rows, item) :
    positions = item.body

    while True:
        x = random.randrange(rows)
        y = random.randrange(rows)
        if len(list(filter(lambda z:z.pos == (x,y), positions))) > 0:
#lambda z is a fucntion. we r checking if this z.pos is equal to x,y. if its equal to x,y we will have to continue it again
            continue
        else:
            break
        
    return (x,y)


def message_box(subject, content) :
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.attributes("-topmost", True)
    root.withdraw()
    messagebox.showinfo(subject, content)
    try:
        root.destroy()
    except:
        pass
    

def main() :
    global width, rows, s, snack
    width = 500
    rows = 20
    win = pygame.display.set_mode((width, width))
    s = snake((255,0,0), (10,10))
    snack = cube(randomSnack(rows, s), color=(0,255,0))
    flag = True

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    
    while flag:
        pygame.time.delay(50)
        clock.tick(10)
        s.move()
        if s.body[0].pos == snack.pos:
            s.addCube()
            snack = cube(randomSnack(rows, s), color=(0,255,0))

        for x in range (len(s.body)):
            if s.body[x].pos in list(map(lambda z:z.pos,s.body[x+1:])):
                print("Score:", len(s.body))
                message_box("Loser!", "Get stressed again?")
                s.reset((10,10))
                break
#looping through every cube in snake body, checking if the pos is in a list of all the positions after
   
        redrawWindow(win)
        
    pass



main()
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Update: I moved my code to VS code and the same thing happens. This is what shows up in the terminal after python unexpected closes:

```
2022-03-12 12:28:55.740 Python[26287:549611] -[SDLApplication macOSVersion]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x141f35cc0
2022-03-12 12:28:55.749 Python[26287:549611] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SDLApplication macOSVersion]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x141f35cc0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001873ac1cc __exceptionPreprocess + 240
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001870fd7b8 objc_exception_throw + 60
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018743f1a0 -[NSObject(NSObject) __retain_OA] + 0
        3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018730c360 ___forwarding___ + 1728
        4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018730bbe0 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 96
        5   libtk8.6.dylib                      0x00000001067acb1c GetRGBA + 64
        6   libtk8.6.dylib                      0x00000001067ac5a8 SetCGColorComponents + 140
        7   libtk8.6.dylib                      0x00000001067ac9e0 TkpGetColor + 544
        8   libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000010670e554 Tk_GetColor + 220
        9   libtk8.6.dylib                      0x0000000106701ba0 Tk_Get3DBorder + 204
        10  libtk8.6.dylib                      0x00000001067019ac Tk_Alloc3DBorderFromObj + 144
        11  libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000010670f910 DoObjConfig + 832
        12  libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000010670f4cc Tk_InitOptions + 348
        13  libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000010670f3c8 Tk_InitOptions + 88
        14  libtk8.6.dylib                      0x0000000106736df0 CreateFrame + 1448
        15  libtk8.6.dylib                      0x00000001067370e8 TkListCreateFrame + 156
        16  libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000010672ffc0 Initialize + 1848
        17  _tkinter.cpython-310-darwin.so      0x00000001062322d4 Tcl_AppInit + 92
        18  _tkinter.cpython-310-darwin.so      0x0000000106231f6c Tkapp_New + 548
        19  _tkinter.cpython-310-darwin.so      0x0000000106231d44 _tkinter_create_impl + 268
        20  _tkinter.cpython-310-darwin.so      0x000000010623197c _tkinter_create + 240
        21  Python                              0x0000000105c2afa4 cfunction_vectorcall_FASTCALL + 88
        22  Python                              0x0000000105cfa160 call_function + 132
        23  Python                              0x0000000105cf2190 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 24188
        24  Python                              0x0000000105ceaae4 _PyEval_Vector + 360
        25  Python                              0x0000000105bc42dc _PyObject_FastCallDictTstate + 96
        26  Python                              0x0000000105c57a3c slot_tp_init + 196
        27  Python                              0x0000000105c4e6d0 type_call + 312
        28  Python                              0x0000000105bc4024 _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 136
        29  Python                              0x0000000105cfa258 call_function + 380
        30  Python                              0x0000000105cf2190 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 24188
        31  Python                              0x0000000105ceaae4 _PyEval_Vector + 360
        32  Python                              0x0000000105cfa160 call_function + 132
        33  Python                              0x0000000105cf042c _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 16664
        34  Python                              0x0000000105ceaae4 _PyEval_Vector + 360
        35  Python                              0x0000000105cfa160 call_function + 132
        36  Python                              0x0000000105cf042c _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 16664
        37  Python                              0x0000000105ceaae4 _PyEval_Vector + 360
        38  Python                              0x0000000105d55534 pyrun_file + 308
        39  Python                              0x0000000105d54c78 _PyRun_SimpleFileObject + 336
        40  Python                              0x0000000105d542c4 _PyRun_AnyFileObject + 216
        41  Python                              0x0000000105d803c4 pymain_run_file_obj + 180
        42  Python                              0x0000000105d7fa64 pymain_run_file + 72
        43  Python                              0x0000000105d7f04c pymain_run_python + 300
        44  Python                              0x0000000105d7eee0 Py_RunMain + 24
        45  Python                              0x0000000105d8056c pymain_main + 56
        46  Python                              0x0000000105d80830 Py_BytesMain + 40
        47  dyld                                0x000000010514d0f4 start + 520
)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
zsh: abort      /usr/local/bin/python3
```

Does it mean anything?

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see which part of code is executed (and what you have in variables). It is called `"print debuging"`. Maybe you mesage box is never executed.

Comment: where do I add the print()?

Comment: good rule: `CamelCaseNames` for classes - ie `class Snake`. It simpler recognize class in code - and later you can do `snake = Snake(..)`

Comment: you can add `print()` even in all places - if it can help you see what code is doing. It can be hard but maybe simpler than learn how to use real debuger.

Comment: @furas Yes. However, in most cases (unless it's quick debugging that might not be useful later), you should use the `logging` module, since it's more convenient in my opinion, although that's a different matter ;)

Comment: @Jonathan you are right, `"print debuging"` is good for small and fast debuging - and we can use it in any language without learing special modules or debugers (when we are beginners in new language). `logging` is next step, and it is useful when program has to run all time without our control.

Answer (score 1):

You made a typo. When you called `messagebox` to display the messagebox, you accidentally put an underscore. Instead of

```
message_box("Loser!", "Get stressed again?")
```

Do:

```
messagebox("Loser!", "Get stressed again?")
```